# NEST Elasticsearch GeoPoint class

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have a field that is specified as GeoPoint in the Index Mapping :

```
.GeoPoint(d => d.Name(c => c.Location))
```

If we create an object and assign this field a value using the following:

```
location = new GeoCoordinate(54.34445, -3.2344)
```

The index show this as a GeoPoint with a value of `-3.2344, 54.34445`

However if we index using a string such as : `"54.34445, -3.2344"` ,the index in Kibana shows this also as a GeoPoint but in the format  `54.34445, -3.2344`

Both cannot be right! as the lat/lon values will be completely different for the same point one is indexing.

In effect, creating the SAME point in 2 different ways as per docs, creates two completely different locations in the index

Answer (score 1):

A `GeoCoordinate` ctor accepts `latitude` and `longitude` in that order (there's an overload to accept an optional `z` value too).

It serializes to `[lon, lat]`, which conforms to the [GeoJSON format RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.1). Well Known Text (WKT), another format used for representing geometries uses the order `x`, `y`, which correspond to `lon` and `lat`.

Coordinates expressed as a string are of the form `lat,lon`. [See the Important admonition in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html).

Comment: Thanks. What I am confused about is what ends up in the actual index as data. I assume irrespective how you define the point at the end of the day it should end up in the index as a GeoPint with coordinates that Elastic knows how to deal with. If you look at the data in the index - if you created the doc using the string it will be stored as lat,lon however if you created the doc using the GeoCoordinate you will see lon,lat in the index. In the index they are both specified as GeoPoint but depending how you index it, they will look like 2 completely different locations.

Comment: For example if there are 2 points in an index both defined as Geo Points : location = 52.6693,-8.56438 and another location = -8.56438 ,52.6693 surely they represent 2 different locations even though they are the same point only one indexed using a string and the other using GeoCoordinates.

Comment: A string of `"lat,lon"` and an array of double `[lon, lat]` represent the same coordinates in two different representations that Elasticsearch can handle. What actually ends up in the inverted index for `geo_point` types is a quad tree encoded 64 bit integer (I don't think they are yet using BKD trees, like `geo_shape` types). The `_source` of each document will reflect verbatim what was sent to Elasticsearch, but searching is not performed on `_source`, but on what is indexed in the _inverted_ index

Comment: Thanks. Got it. What we kept seeing in Kibana was confusing us.

Comment: Sorry - Just as point for completeness for this topic, when you convert the source to an object and try and get the lat/lon for each of these points will they come out correctly and how does Elastic know based on this verbatim which was indexed in which way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple [ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) of defining/displaying coordinates, most notably either a string of the format `"lat,lon"`, or an array of the form `[lon,lat]`.

Note that Kibana most probably sticks to only one format (`"lat,lon"` -- `54.34445, -3.2344` is in the UK, the reverse off the Somalian coast) while indexing doc values supports multiple.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that. But creating the SAME point in 2 different ways as per docs, creates two completely different locations in the index!